# Como exibir as coordenadas do GPS

Tags: android, android-studio, gps, coordenadas

Pessoal sou novato estou cursando `Sistemas de Informação` e foi proposto um trabalho no qual precisa usar um elemento de hardware do celular.

Optei por fazer um aplicativo que exiba as coordenadas, eu digito manualmente o nome do local e depois salva um arquivo `txt` dentro da memória do celular.

Gostaria de dicas: livros, sites, manuais ou documentações para desenvolver este app no **Android Studio**.

Comment: Raphael, me parece que sua pergunta é um pouco ampla, pois vai desde a criação do aplicativo até a gravação das coordenadas em um arquivo, é isso? Sugiro você segmentar essas dúvidas, até para ter algo que você tenha tentado fazer para que possamos trabalhar em uma dúvida específica sua, assim fica mais claro e direcionado.

Comment: @Paulo, você entendeu errado. Ele deseja saber quais são as bases para desenvolver o **app** com a funcionalidade de pegar um local e salvar sua coordenada em um arquivo de texto no sistema do dispositivo. E sim, a última parte do texto deixa a entender que ele deseja saber como criar o aplicativo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesse livro você encontrará exemplo utilizando GPS no Android (E é um livro voltado a iniciantes na plataforma, no meu ponto de vista): http://www.casadocodigo.com.br/pages/sumario-android

Tem também os seguintes links:
http://www.thiengo.com.br/gps-triangulacao-de-antenas-e-locationsource-no-android
http://blog.caelum.com.br/usando-o-google-maps-e-gps-no-android/

E a documentação do Google:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

E pra finalizar, no AndroidStudio, na aba File > Import Sample. Você pode importar o exemplo que a equipe do Android fez, ao qual utiliza recursos de Location Google APIs. O nome do projeto é: XYZTouristAttractions Sample
Você pode ver detalhes dele no GitHub também: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/

Espero ter ajudado!
Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Aqui [nesse link](http://mariovalney.com/android) eu estou ensinando a criar um Aplicativo para Android, para o que você quer aprender, basta ler as aulas de 1 a 7.

Como ainda não terminei o curso, falta coisa para o que você quer aprender, mas depois de ler vai ficar mais fácil pesquisar como usar a [API do Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/?hl=pt-br) para Android e outras dúvidas pontuais, por exemplo, [como persistir dados num app Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) ([outro link](http://www.rafaeltoledo.net/tutorial-android-11-persistencia-em-banco-de-dados/), agora em PT).